# continue delete char from edit text after settext edit text android

Tags: android, android-edittext

how to continue delete char from edit text after settext edit text when button delete keybord is perssed true?

```
edtDesc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        String formatNumber = "";


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            edtDesc.setSelection(edtDesc.getText().length());

        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            if (s.length() != 0) {
                    edtDesc.setText(edtDesc.getText().toString().replace("A", "B"));
                    isSelectTozihat = true;
            }

        }

    });
```

thanks

Comment: I don't understand you question. Can you try to be more clear? Maybe i can help you.

Comment: after set text to edit text and press button delete keyboard.only delete one char.i want continue delete char....

Comment: Still in don't full understand. After set text in a EditText, if the user press the delete button only one, this action only delete one character, but you wish that after click once, all the text should be dissappered ???

Comment: if user press and hold delete button i want continue delete char.i don't want delete all text of edit text.

Answer (score 0):

```
edtDesc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    String formatNumber = "";


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        edtDesc.setSelection(edtDesc.getText().length());

    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        if ((s.length() != 0)&&(edtDesc.getText().toString().contains("A"))      {
edtDesc.setText(edtDesc.getText().toString().replace("A", "B"));
                isSelectTozihat = true;
        }

    }

});
```